# Two interpretations of “she looks pretty shook up from the letter"

Tags: meaning

Consider:

> She looks pretty shook up from the letter

At first I interpreted this as, "She is pretty upset after reading the letter", but on the second thought, I wondered if maybe it could be saying, "From her letter, she seems to be quite upset. (In the first scenario, she would be the one reading the letter. In the second scenario, the letter would be written by her, but it would be read by someone else.)

Which understanding is right?

Comment: Additional context would be helpful, although I don't think the second interpretation is likely; one doesn't *look* shook up when being described in a letter so much as *sound* or *seem* it.

Comment: ...or she looks like she was delivered in the envelope and someone shook her out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both interpretations are possible. The context would disambiguate. If she has read a letter, then the sentence means that the way she looks indicates that she is upset due to the content of the letter. If she has written a letter, then the sentence means that the content of the letter indicates that she is upset.

That being said, the interpretation that first came to my mind is the first one. I agree with [choster's comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/12007/two-interpretations-of-she-looks-pretty-shook-up-from-the-letter#comment20500_12007) that *seems* or *sounds* would be prefered to *looks* to indicate an impression conveyed through a written text. Still, even if the verb had been the neutral *seems*, I think the first interpretation would be the default one, but the context can override this impression.

If you absolutely wanted to disambiguate, you could say:

> Looks like the letter shook her up some.
> The letter seems to have rather shaken her up.
>
> From the letter, seems she's pretty shook up.
> From the letter, she seems pretty shaken up.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose if you could physically see the speaker, and he was indicating the letter by pointing to it or shaking it, and you know who the letter was from, and were waiting to her about her status, he might say "She looks pretty shook up from the letter," in your second sense above. But 99% of the time, the sentence would be interpreted the first way. If, in general, I wanted to indicate that I learned from a female correspondent  that she was upset, I'd say "She *sounds* pretty upset from the letter."